# Airflow Open Source Contribution

Tags: airflow

I have worked on a few enhancements in Airflow 1.10. 
I wanted to know , if I need a CLA ( Contributors Licence Agreement ) to push my code to Airflow Open Source.

I am working for an Enterprise.

Comment: Consider that the code may belong to your company. In this case, you will need a permission from you company to release the code under the Apache license.

Comment: Thanks @SergiyKolesnikov, You are correct, To get an approval from my company , I need to find out if Committing back to Apache Airflow need a CLA or not.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably best directed at the Airflow proper community, how to do this can be found in the `CONTRIBUTING.md` file.

Comment: Thanks @Mike, I have gone through this doc but it has no mention of any CLA. My company wont approve the request until this point has been clarified enough. I have recently joined the Apache Airflow slack and have raised a question there. I will update here if i get an appropriate reply .
Meanwhile, if you find anything that helps me , that would be great too.
Thanks again :) .